# JavaScript weird issue

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

i have an issue with a site that i cool development over. I am working on a website that is using the same WordPress install and shares the same DB, however, it was built with the intention to display 3 different phone numbers in the header area. Since the 3 sites share the same WordPress install the original developer wrote a script in the header.php that user a set of var and id to reference the number in the header.

If you understand JavaScript this is very simple to read and understand. The code uses the set var to reflect the 3 numbers in the if statements and it works to a point. The website has the main header and then a sticky subheader once the user scrolls down the page, so the number goes from the main header into the sticky subheader. The problem is that instead of showing the set number the subheader displays the number I use as the reference and not the set number. So I cannot understand why it's doing that since its using the same reference code.

I would like to keep the website private, however here is the script below that is in the header.php file.

```
// GET BASE URL
var base_url = window.location.hostname;
var set_phone = '(602) 457-5857';

if(base_url === "www.website1.com" || base_url === "website1.com" || base_url === "www.website2.com" || base_url === "website2.com" || base_url === "www.website3.com" || base_url === "website3")
{

if(base_url === "website1" || base_url === "website1"){
    set_phone = '(602) 900-9399';
} else if(base_url === "website2" || base_url === "website2"){
    set_phone = '(602) 714-1527';
} else if(base_url === "website3" || base_url === "website3"){
    set_phone = '(602) 293-8086';
}
document.getElementById("number_link").innerHTML = set_phone;

jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {

    $("#number_link").attr("href", "tel:"+set_phone);


});
 // $("#number_link").html(set_phone);

}
```

and here is the code that is used in the header but changes in the subheader.

```
<i class="icon-phone8"></i>Call Us: <a href="tel:602-457-5857" id="number_link">602-457-5857</a>
```

if anyone can give me some ideas that be great!!! Thank you in advance

Comment: Are you having same `id="number_link"` in main header and sticky header?

Comment: So is the phone number in more than one place? Really impossible to tell/help, we can only guess.

Comment: afaik you have 3 links in your page with the id `number_link`. IDs are supposed to be unique. Probably it is selecting the wrong node. Yes definitely, two are wrong, and only one has the right phone number

Comment: So the id="number_link" is in the header section of the theme options, and the sticky sub header is just and on/off switch in that same section of the theme options. There is short text area where the code can be placed and that is there this part of the code is placed.<i class="icon-phone8"></i>Call Us: <a href="tel:602-457-5857" id="number_link">602-457-5857</a>

Comment: @espascarello yes the phone number is in the header of the website, once the user scrolls down the page the subheader appears and the main header disappears, however, the phone number drops down to the subheader but it keeps displaying the reference var number instead of the if statement number that was set up.

Comment: @Thomas im not sure i understand what you mean, could you write it out in code if that possible.